# Why is n+++n valid while n++++n is not?

Tags: java, syntax, tokenize

In Java, the expression:

```
n+++n
```

Appears to evaluate as equivalent to:

```
n++ + n
```

Despite the fact that `+n` is a valid unary operator with higher precedence than the arithmetic `+` operator in `n + n`.  So the compiler appears to be assuming that the operator cannot be the unary operator and resolving the expression.

However, the expression:

```
n++++n
```

Does not compile, even though there is a single valid possibility for it to be resolved as:

```
n++ + +n
```

`++n` and `+n` are specified as having the same precedence, so why does the compiler resolve the seeming ambiguity in `n+++n` in favour of the arithmetic `+` but does not do so with `n++++n`?

Comment: You should include the compiler error in question.

Comment: It's probably compiler-dependent, because I'm using Eclipse here and I just tested the `n+++n` statement here, and Eclipse tells me it's invalid.

Comment: by your logic, `++n` should be interpreted as `+(+n)`, which would make `++n` impossible

Comment: @Mauren interesting, when I test it in eclipse it compiles and give me a result of 3 when `n` is set to 1 initially.

Comment: @increment1 maybe it's the JDK. I just tested via javac and got this: `$ javac Teste.java 
Teste.java:7: not a statement
    n+++n;
       ^
1 error`. Can you provide your full code snippet?

Comment: @Mauren `n+++n;` isn't valid as a standalone statement. The question is about the *expression* `n+++n`. Try `x = n+++n;`.

Comment: Any expression n+...+n with an odd number of + is a valid expression, see http://cui.unige.ch/isi/bnf/JAVA/numeric_expression.html.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I haven't noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: @amadeus I get a compiler error (at least in eclipse) when trying `n+++++n`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The file is tokenized (transformed into sequence of tokens) first with the maximal munch rule - always get longest possible valid token. Your text is transformed to following sequence:

```
n ++ ++ n
```

And this is not valid expression.

From [JLS §3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2):

> ### 3.2. Lexical Translations
>
> A raw Unicode character stream is translated into a sequence of tokens, using the following three
>   lexical translation steps, which are applied in turn:
>
> 1. A translation of Unicode escapes (§3.3) in the raw stream of Unicode
>      characters to the corresponding Unicode character. A Unicode escape
>      of the form \uxxxx, where xxxx is a hexadecimal value, represents
>      the UTF-16 code unit whose encoding is xxxx. This translation step
>      allows any program to be expressed using only ASCII characters.
> 2. A translation of the Unicode stream resulting from step 1 into a stream of input characters and line terminators (§3.4).
> 3. A translation of the stream of input characters and line terminators resulting from step 2 into a sequence of input elements
>      (§3.5) which, after white space (§3.6) and comments (§3.7) are
>      discarded, comprise the tokens (§3.5) that are the terminal symbols
>      of the syntactic grammar (§2.3).
>
> **The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another
>   lexical translation would.**
>
> (Thus, the input characters `a--b` are tokenized (§3.5) as `a, --, b`,
>   which is not part of any grammatically correct program, even though
>   the tokenization `a, -, -, b` could be part of a grammatically correct
>   program.)

Comment: Where is this "rule" documented? Can we count on this behavior?

Comment: @user814064 - yes, I added text and example from Java 7 spec. Maximal munch is common in language definitions.

Comment: Thanks! Above people were implying this was compiler-dependent behavior.

Comment: Is tokenization done right to left for operators?  After further testing `n+++n` actually evaluates as `n + ++n`, which indicates a right to left tokenization, although one would assume that tokenization was left to right.  I cannot find any clarity on this in the JLS.

Comment: @increment1 - it goes left to right, but note that `n++ +n` and `n+ ++n` are equivalent. Both are like: `a = n; n++; b = n; return a + b;`

Comment: @zch Sigh, correct.. and my update to my post is wrong.  I had switched it to `a+++b` to verify which tokenization was being done (`++ +` or `+ ++`), unfortunately I appear to have misread my results and it is in fact `++ +`.  Thanks for your detailed answer!